# Matplotlib provokes MemoryError on Ubuntu 18.04 but not on Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am developing software on my Ubuntu machine for a Windows user.

What it does:
Making an object detection on thousands of images and compare the result to some measurement data (oscilloscope data: ~200MB, 50 million data values). In the end the result is plotted and saved. After this step, the program advances to the next dataset and so on. At the second dataset, I am getting the Error.

I have installed both Ubuntu and Windows 10 64-bit version. Python3 64bit should run on both OS.

To start the python script you just run it, and it does all the work in a large for loop. Basic steps:

1. Detect objects on images of dataset 1
2. Make some calculations
3. Plot results with matplotlib and save to file
4. Advance to next dataset
5. Detect objects on images of dataset 2
6. Make some calculations
7. Plot results [MemoryError]

Since just copying the whole ErrorMessage ends up in destroying its format, I have to insert newlines after every line to make it readable:

```
Progress: Datensatz 1/2 ; Sequenz 2/4 ; Frame 99/101

Progress: Datensatz 1/2 ; Sequenz 2/4 ; Frame 100/101

Progress: Datensatz 1/2 ; Sequenz 2/4 ; Frame 101/101

Progress: Plot...

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1496, in _getbool_axis
    return self.obj._take(inds, axis=axis)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2789, in _take
    verify=True)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4539, in take
    axis=axis, allow_dups=True)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4421, in reindex_indexer
    fill_tuple=(fill_value,))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4501, in _slice_take_blocks_ax0
    fill_tuple=None))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 1254, in take_nd
    allow_fill=False)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 1653, in take_nd
    out = np.empty(out_shape, dtype=dtype, order='F')

MemoryError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/artur/Desktop/UHF_Analyse_Artur/Firefly_Gesamt/UHF_Analyse.py", line 794, in <module>
    plot(gap_list, deg_list, timestamp, trc)

  File "/home/artur/Desktop/UHF_Analyse_Artur/Firefly_Gesamt/UHF_Analyse.py", line 306, in plot
    xticks = np.arange(df_oszi.index[0], df_oszi.index[-1], 1))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 2941, in __call__
    sort_columns=sort_columns, **kwds)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 1977, in plot_frame
    **kwds)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 1804, in _plot
    plot_obj.generate()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 258, in generate
    self._compute_plot_data()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 363, in _compute_plot_data
    "timedelta"])

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3091, in select_dtypes
    return self.loc[com._get_info_slice(self, dtype_indexer)]

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1472, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 890, in _getitem_tuple
    retval = getattr(retval, self.name)._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1868, in _getitem_axis
    return self._getbool_axis(key, axis=axis)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1498, in _getbool_axis
    raise self._exception(detail)

KeyError: MemoryError()

>>> Exception in Tkinter callback

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 749, in callit
    func(*args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 346, in idle_draw
    self.draw()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 9, in draw
    super(FigureCanvasTkAgg, self).draw()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 402, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1649, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 138, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2610, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 138, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 736, in draw
    self._transform_path(subslice)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 688, in _transform_path
    _path = Path(np.asarray(xy).T,

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 492, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

MemoryError
```

The funny part about this is that I get the `MemoryError` on Ubuntu but not on Windows. I always thought python runs much more reliable on Linux. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: One cannot know the reason for an error without seeing the code that is responsible for the error. (See [mcve])

Comment: The code is a thousand lines long. I do not think that posting it here would help, would it? I don't know how to isolate/reconstruct the Error.

Comment: Well, that's the idea behind a minimal verifiable example. Constructing such example is hard; but necessary, unless you feel that what you're asking here does not require someone to be able to reproduce the error?