# A simple way of freeing Memory in python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, garbage-collection

For some time now, I am trying to solve my memory issues. I wrote a program to plot (and save the fig) oscilloscope `.trc` files. These contain **100 million** data points. `Matplotlib` can plot one file but as soon as I put the plot operation in a `for loop`, it throws a `MemoryError`. The reason I put the plot operation into a `for loop` is that I am writing a program to loop through many datasets and save the plot of each in a folder.

I tried resampling but it does not provide a good solution. The dataset is a UHF measurement, which consists of very short impulses. Each impulse can consist of **3 datapoints** out of **100 million**. So when I resample (reduce the amount of data) it leads to data loss. Example:

Original Dataset:

[image]

Resampled Dataset, `sampling factor = 10`:

[image]

As you see, some of the impulses are cut short.

The big question is why python is not freeing Memory after the `plot function` has been completed. My program works like this:

1. Begin `for loop`
2. Analyze Dataset 1
3. Execute Plot Function
4. Analyze Dataset 2
5. Execute Plot Function `[MemoryError]`

The `Plot Function` uses `pd.DataFrames()`, `lists` and `variables` to plot the graph. The `figure` is not shown but saved as a `.png` file into a folder. Why is python not freeing Memory after the `plot function` is completed?

I have been trying to free Memory manually with `garbage collector` but have not been able to manage. There should be enough Memory for one loop, so shouldn't it be possible to free Memory in the end of each loop? Is there a proper way for doing this with `gc`?

I tried to put this at the end of the `plot function` but am still getting the `MemoryError`:

```
del dataframes, lists, variables
gc.collect()
```

**Edit:**

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import readTrc

foldername = 'trc_folder'
folder = os.listdir(foldername)
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

for filenumber, i in enumerate(folder):
    trc = path + '/' + foldername + '/' + i

    print('reading trc file ' + str(filenumber))

    datX, datY, d = readTrc.Trc().open(trc)
    srx, sry = pd.Series(datX * 1000), pd.Series(datY * 1000)
    df_oszi = pd.concat([srx, sry], axis = 1)
    df_oszi.set_index(0, inplace = True)
    df_oszi.plot(grid = 1,
                 color = 'blue',
                 linewidth = 0.5,
                 figsize = (9,5),
                 legend = False,
                 xticks = np.arange(df_oszi.index[0], df_oszi.index[-1], 1))

    print('plotting file ' + str(filenumber))
    plt.savefig('Plot_' + str(filenumber) + '.png', dpi = 300)
    plt.close('all')
```

Comment: You need to provide your actual code if you want help. The way you are creating figures and axes, and disposing of them is probably relevant

Comment: I have no particular way of disposing of figures/axes. I just start the next loop. Should I dispose of them? I thought if I give an old variable the same name, memory would be freed automatically?

Comment: If you are running out of memory, either you have to create a single figure/Axes and keep reusing them in your loop (my prefered option), or delete each figure after you've saved them. But it's impossible to know what is the best approach without seeing your code

Comment: Please see the edit section. I've tried to delete the figures in the past with `plt.close('all')` but it had no effect on the `MemoryError`. If you want I can upload the data files `.trc` but they are 200MB each.

Comment: First of all: please try not to ask about the same things multiple times. Secondly: you can not possible learn *anything* about the "dense" region in your plot without zooming in / discarding some of the data (your monitor can't resolve the points, matplotlib will already select what you are shown!). From your previous questions, it sounds like you are not even interested in that regions, so why not simply remove the unnecessary data and solve your memory issue that way?

Comment: 1. There is no solution to my last question. 2. The questions are not the same. One is about how to prevent `MemoryError` while plotting. The other is how to free Memory. 3. It seems you know better than me how my dataset looks. When I make the effort to point out that resampling doesn't work because of said reasons, I might have tried. Nonetheless, thank you for your concern regarding my questions. The reason I am stressing this is that I was not able to find a solution for this problem.

Comment: I did not want to offend, just wanted to point out that there's your [initial `MemoryError` question, which you didn't edit to improve it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55773648/), rather created [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55790403/) where I *potentially* found the issue (too much data) and gave you four *potential ideas for a solution*, and this question still circles about the `MemoryError`. It's fine if you do this, it's just likely better to *keep attention focused* by staying within one question if the parameters don't change. But that's just my opinion! :)

Comment: In principle you are right, if one loop iteration works, others should as well; *under the condition*  that all files have the same number of data in them. Have you verified that? One concern here is the use of `xticks = ...`. What is its purpose? What happens if you remove it? Also could you put your attempt of deleting variables and garbage collection *into*  the actual code such that one can see if it is done correctly?